# Simulate key with Laravel Dusk (without input element)

Tags: laravel-dusk, laravel-dusk2

I have a page which consists of some disabled inputs, spans and divs.
In the background I wait for pressed keys. Background of this is some memory game.
My problem is, that it turned out to be pretty hard to test.
I know two functions to simulate input: `type()` and `keys()`. When I use `keys("@someElement", "34")`, I get "element not interactable". Similar happens with `type()` (well that's not surprising as type suggests filling some input).

How can I properly simulate a pressed key without using an active input element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the underlying driver:

```php
$browser->driver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys('a');
$browser->driver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys(\Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverKeys::ENTER);
```